# Create an object from a text which represents the class name

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I do not know if this is possible but I am storing the output of type(...) in a string.
The output is a class created by me:

```
type(...) -> <class 'apps.X.Y.Z.Listings'>
```

I am storing this as a text but later I want to use this to create an object.
How can it be done?
I used exec and did not worked and also callable says that is False.

In which format should I store to be able to convert the string into the class name and instantiate an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If class is imported you can use `globals()`

```
globals()["Listings"]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
eval(<string_class>)()
```